# iOS7 background fetch performFetchWithCompletionHandler does not work on device when not connected to xcode debug mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I implemented the performFetchWithCompletionHandler for background fetch. I have local notifications setup to fire when there is change in data. For test purposes I also had notifications to fire even when there is no change in data so that I know things are actually working, and I don't have to wait for remote data to change to test my app).

With the app in debug mode in xcode, I use the "Simulate Background fetch" option, and background fetch works as expected. Notifications are displayed on the simulator as expected.

Deleted the old app on the phone. I connect the ip5 device to xcode and run the app. App is updated on iphone. When in debug mode, I execute the "Simulate Background fetch" option. I see local notifications as I expected.

now I have disconnected the device and I have been opening and closing the app every hour (amlost!), but background fetch has not fired even once, and I have not seen any local notification yet.

I have set the code to do this:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];

    return YES;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 5 Debug mode, you can force a background fetch from the menu: Debug > Simulate Background Fetch.

Please check this link 
[performFetchWithCompletionHandler never gets fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18315771/performfetchwithcompletionhandler-never-gets-fired)

Answer (score 0):

Hoping that this is not the case:

What type of background fetch are you doing? It is possible that the fetch may work once in the debugger and not again - and then when you run an actual IPA, because you are, for example, doing a dataTaskWithRequest or something similar - that it won't work.