# Background fetch, testing problems

Tags: ios, react-native, background-fetch

I have a react-native application which includes [react-native-background-task](https://github.com/jamesisaac/react-native-background-task) which uses [react-native-background-fetch](https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-fetch). I configured a job to console.log a simple message when it runs. I understand that the background fetch is not working on simulator, but you can test it by going into `Debug -> Simulate background fetch`. When I hit this, the app goes to background. I did not get any output. I have enabled background fetch in Info.plis and also the code returns status.available when I check with the library function.
How do you actually test this?

```
Xcode 8.3.3
react-native 0.44.0
react-native-background-fetch 2.0.8 
react-native-background-task 0.2.1



class App extends Component {
componentWillMount() {
  BackgroundTaks.define(() => {
    console.log('==================FETCH==================');
    console.log('task running');
    console.log('====================================');

    BackgroundTaks.finish();
  });
}

componentDidMount() {
  BackgroundTaks.schedule();
}

render() {
  return (
    <Router />
  );
}}
```

export default App;

I am getting [the same breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39623664/why-is-simulate-background-fetch-leading-to-crash-libsystem-kernel-dylibmach) when I Simulate background fetch using real device

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap:
    0x186e9721c <+0>: mov    x16, #-0x1f
    0x186e97220 <+4>: svc    #0x80
->  0x186e97224 <+8>: ret
```

Comment: Xcode menu > Debug > Simulate Background Fetch

Comment: @Desdenova That is what I am doing, did you read it ?

Comment: Appearantly not :) Sorry

Comment: Please add [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. At the end I realized the background fetch checkbox was not checked in the project settings. After checking it does work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've mentioned that you've tried writing to storage also - which is not working - my updated answer would be: while you are running background fetch, you can at the same time hit a server on which you can see the logs. That way, you can tell, if the background fetch was successfully working.

I've created a hackable [localTestingServer](https://github.com/prabodhprakash/localTestingServer) that you can fork and get started immediately.

Comment: I edit the question. I tried using storage as well but there was no result after simulating background fetch. I even installed it on the device and let it run for a while but the storage was not updated

Comment: How does this lead to narrowing down the possible problem, when all I do is run a background task to set a dummy string to storage or print an output? It does not run the task at all and throws the exception I added to the question.

Comment: Because now you can send logs to some server in place. Depends on your imagination to solve a problem